# Vue - How to create interactive func for textarea and input field?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a textarea that is used to generate the input field group, but i wanna do a function is even I change the input field, the textarea also change the value. I already created the Vue js for textarea to input field but I cannot reverse. Any solution for this case?

## Textarea

```
<v-row>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
        <v-textarea
            v-model="groupTask"
            dense
            :hide-details="true"
            outlined
            label="Group Task"
        ></v-textarea>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

## input field

```
<v-row v-for="(item, index) in tasks">
    <v-col cols="12" sm="4">
        <v-text-field
            dense
            :hide-details="true"
            outlined
            :label="'Group Task Number ('+ (index+1) + ')'"
            :name="tasksList[index]"
            v-model="item.number"
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="4">
        <v-text-field
            dense
            :hide-details="true"
            outlined
            :label="'Group Task Name ('+ (index+1) + ')'"
            :name="tasksList[index]"
            v-model="item.task"
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="12" sm="4">
        <v-text-field
            dense
            :hide-details="true"
            outlined
            :label="'Group Task Price ('+ (index+1) + ')'"
            :name="tasksList[index]"
            v-model="item.price"
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
```

## Vue Code

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            tasks: [],
            groupTask: "",
            tasksList: [],
        };
    },
    watch: {
        groupTask: function(newValue, oldValue) {
            let data = newValue.split("\n");
            let item = Math.ceil(newValue.split("\n").length / 3);
            this.tasks = [];
            for (var loop = 0; loop < item; loop++) {
                let tmp = data.slice(loop * 3, loop * 3 + 3);
                this.tasks.push({
                    number: tmp[0],
                    task: tmp[1],
                    price: tmp[2]
                });
            }
        },
    },
    computed: {},
    methods: {},
    created() {}
};
</script>
```

[image: That is what I want]

Comment: Can you explain your actual inputs and outputs of your code? Without understanding that it is hard to tell how to reverse it

Comment: Im just uploaded the image. When i type 1\n\2\n3\n4\n5\n6, it will generate a group of input 3 row = 1 group (Eg,1,2,3 will be a group of the tasks). One more thing is that is dynamic to generate the group task and now I cannot change the group task value when i change the input field value.

Comment: Ok I have updated my answer below, can you check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getters` and `setters` in a `computed` property and create interdependency between two varaibles.

There is no need for `watchers`

```js
export default {
  data() {
      return {
          tasks: [],
          tasksList: [],
      };
  },
  computed: {
    groupTask: {
      get() {
        return this.tasksList.map(task => [task.number, task.task, tast.price]).flat().join("\n"); // your reverse code to generate groupTask string from tasksList array here
      },
      set(newVal) {
        let data = newValue.split("\n");
            let item = Math.ceil(newValue.split("\n").length / 3);
            this.tasks = [];
            for (var loop = 0; loop < item; loop++) {
                let tmp = data.slice(loop * 3, loop * 3 + 3);
                this.tasks.push({
                    number: tmp[0],
                    task: tmp[1],
                    price: tmp[2]
                });
            }
      }
    }
  }
```

You can learn more about computed properties and it's getters and setters from here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Comment: Um... I have been tried your code, it seems cannot change the new value to textarea when i change the input field value

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed for groupTask and make textarea readonly or use item.task for v-model of textarea.

```
computed: {
    groupTask() {
        return item.task;
    }
}
```

Update:
watch method:

```
watch:{
     'item.task': (newVal, oldVal) => {
         this.groupTask = newVal;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Then you can use second method, directly use item.task for v-model of textarea. Or you can watch item.task and change value of groupTask. I just updated answer and added it.